# Docker application live upgrade

Tags: linux, docker, fork, high-availability

I'm new to docker, and have some problems designing a simple live upgrade solution when docker is involved. Currently I'm using a `fork()/exec()` based pattern for application live upgrade:

- The old server `fork()` a child when requested.
- The child server `exec()` new executable, load new data/configuration.
- The old server passes necessary information (socket, memory data, etc.) to the child server so it can take over the service.
- The old server stops processing new requests after child is ready (the old server won't `exit()` ATM).
- If the upgrade is successful, stop the old server manually (this can be delayed until shortly before the next live upgrade), otherwise stop the child server and inform the old server to restart processing requests.

As you can see, this live upgrade strategy usually cause no downtime whether the upgrade is failed or not.

Most of our services are stateless or have very simple states, so the above pattern can be easily implemented, and it's very reliable.

My question is how can the above pattern (or something similar) be implemented in docker ? Maybe I'm going a wrong direction, I'm all ears.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a load balancer in front of your servers?

Comment: @hek2mgl We have, the upgrade process would be much longer if the the load balancer is involved. Because of the instant rollback feature of this system, we can upgrade the whole system (almost) automatically. If anything went wrong during the automatic upgrade, we can take down all new servers and restart old servers instantly.

Answer (score 1):

As your services are already stateless and handling old connections and new connections at the same time is also possible for your services, using a load balancer in front of your services and some kind of rolling upgrade strategy is what probably fits best.

The fork approach does not fit well into the ideas behind Docker and containers in general. A Docker image and the resulting containers should always contain everything needed to run the service. Also, if another container is started based on the same image, it should always start exactly the same service.

In the fork based upgrade solution, binaries/executables inside the containers would change after initial startup. This means that if for whatever reason you decide to start another container based on that same image, it will not run the same version of the service. You could of course add something to your images that does auto upgrade to the latest version on startup, but this would complicate deployment. And in my opinion, this would violate just too many of the written and unwritten rules in the Docker world and I would consider this bad practice.

I have the feeling that plain Docker is not enough for what you want to use it. I'd suggest that you look into more advanced container orchestration solutions which offer features like service loadbalancing and rolling updates. Kubernetes is the first thing that always comes to my mind when people have these more advanced requirements.

With the introduction of `Deployment` objects, Kubernetes gained a lot of power regarding update strategies. You should read through [Kubernetes Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/). If used with proper health checks, the rolling update strategy of the `Deployment` should give you everything you need, including rollback of failed deployments.

The disadvantage of Kubernetes is the increased effort needed to setup and maintain the clusters. But depending on the size of your application, infrastructure and number of services, it may be worth the effort.